# New functions in module not 'seen' by iPython notebook

Tags: python, function, module, jupyter-notebook

I recently got a new computer (my first Mac, I had a PC before). I have a module full of data analysis functions I use for my research, and I hadn't had any cause to edit the module until now. But suddenly, when I import the module in a Jupyter notebook, the new functions aren't 'seen'.

```
import altdata as alt
alt.retrieve_data_from_umiami_latlonam('GISS','AQUA', 'ts')
```

And this raises the following error:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
----
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-3-9ccbc97fd6b8> in <module>()
1 
 ----> 2 alt.retrieve_data_from_umiami_latlonam('GISS','AQUA', 'ts')

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'retrieve_data_from_umiami_latlonam'
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what the problem is. When try through the command line it works perfectly, but for some reason the new functions don't work in a notebook. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

It seems that when I open the notebook in the directory where the module is located (/mymodules) it works.

When I open it in the directory that contains mymodules and use

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'/mymodules')
import altdata as alt
```

I get the error. Any ideas?

Comment: you probably have the module in multiple paths listed in your PYTHON_PATH. Instead of `sys.path.append(r'/mymodules')` add it to the beginning of the path, that should solve the problem. I.e., `sys.path.insert(0, r'/mymodules')`

Comment: Not quite; I changed the pathname and it fixed it. `sys.path.append("/mymodules")` worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: glad that it works now. In general, I'd still recommend `sys.path.insert(0, '/some_module')` over `append`, because Python scans the sys.path list sequentially for packages, and if it finds the package in an earlier path listed there, it wouldn't bother using the path you appended

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified you module after starting the notebook and importing the module for the for first time in that notebook? In that case, you could try to reload it, e.g,.  `importlib.reload(module)`. If this doesn't help, try restarting the notebook and re-import the module to check if this solves the problem.

Comment: I have restarted the kernel, it does nothing. I have tried it in a new notebook. Also nothing

Comment: I actually closed all notebooks and restarted Jupyter and that seems to have worked. If anyone has a good explanation of *why* this happened though, I would appreciate it; this never happened on my PC and it's extremely tiresome. I edit the module regularly

Comment: If you don't have the module as `altdata.py` in the session's directory/path, then it imports it from some installation dir in your PYTHON_PATH. Maybe you made the changes and forgot to update the installation? You can check from where it's importing via `altdata.__file__` after you imported `altdata`

Comment: I usually tell it where to look explicitly each time. I'm not much of a comp sci guy so I don't usually think too hard about these things until they break. I'll keep that tool for checking in my back pocket though for the future